# Immutable _.assign (assign with clone) from lodash underscore or other library?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is there an alternative method available in lodash, underscore or other library that almost behaves the same way, except that it returns a new object instead of mutating the first argument?.

```
var o = { 'user': 'barney' }
var result = method(o, { 'age': 40 }, { 'user': 'fred' })

// o still { 'user': 'barney' }
// result is now { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }
```

Comment: Sorry, while extracting the object as local variable o, I forgot to replace the snippet I extracted.

Comment: The actual intention as I've said is to  create a new object similar to o, but overriden by succeeding objects. This makes sure that I have versions of o before and after overriding.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The most common way of doing this seems to use an empty object and assign onto that, like:

```
var result = _.assign({}, l, m, n, o, p);
```

This is not technically immutable but will produce a "new" object that did not exist before the function was called.

Bear in mind that even a very clever implementation of clone would have to do this same thing. It's trivial to create the new object manually, so most libraries don't worry about a helper for this case. The next closest thing would be `_.create`, which has more to do with assigning the correct prototype.

Answer (score 7):

I like [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) for cases like this.

```
var user = { user: 'barney', age: 36 };

_.defaults({ age: 40 }, user);
// → { user: 'barney', age: 40 }

user;
// → { user: 'barney', age: 36 }
```

The first argument is the destination, and `user` isn't mutated. I like using `defaults()` when I need to override properties, as is the case here with `age`, but don't want to actually change anything in the original. Because `defaults()` will only add properties that resolve to `undefined`. The `age` property exists in the object literal, so it's value is kept.

The `assign()` approach works just as well - `defaults()` is just a different way to think about it.

Comment: From documentation for lodash 4.13: "Note: This method mutates object."
https://lodash.com/docs#defaults

Comment: Yes, but it's mutating the first object, so if you put your "extra" stuff before the "default" object, then it's the new object that get mutated, not the pre-existing object.  The downside is that you have to put your extra stuff before the default object -- which feels backwards.

Comment: Please note a value of `null` will be kept intact, since it's not `undefined`. The same is true for `_.defaultsDeep()`. In most real life scenarios, `null` should be overridden. The alternative is to use [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) and handle cases as needed. Additionally, naming the customizer function allows recurrency.

Answer (score 5):

The functional programming variant of lodash `assign` does not mutate no arguments :)

Try this:

```
import { assign } from 'lodash/fp';
// or:
// import _ from 'lodash/fp';

const a = {a: 1};
const b = {b: 1};
const c = assign(a, b);

// Results after assign operation:
// a: {a: 1}
// b: {b: 1}
// c: {a: 1, b: 1}
```

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide

Use `merge` (the FP version of `merge` is also immutable) for recursively merging nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [immutable-js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js)

```
var result = Immutable.Map(o).merge({ age: 40, user: 'fred' }).toObject();
console.log(result); // { user: 'fred', age: 40 }
console.log(o); // { user: 'barney' }
```

Comment: I've been looking at ``immutable-js``, however it seems to have problems with  operating with other libraries such as ``lodash``. I've looked at seamless-immutable which offers backwards compatibility with Arrays and objects, however I'm not sure how it measures up with immutable-js.

Comment: Have you tried using the `toJS()` and `fromJS()` methods? These seem to work pretty well for me.

Comment: I just find them a bit clunky. I do think they are funtional though.